# Find the condition that the diagonals of a parallelogram formed by $ax+by+c=0$.

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the condition that the.diagonals of a parallelogram formed by $ax+by+c=0$, $ax+by+c'=0$, $a'x+b'y+c=0$ and $a'x+b'y+c'=0$ are at right angles.

My Attempt:

The equation of diagonal passing through the point of intersection of $ax+by+c=0$ and $a'x+b'y+c=0$ is 
$$(ax+by+c)+ K(a'x+b'y+c)=0$$
Where $K$ is any arbitrary constant.

Again, The equation of the diagonal passing through the point of intersection of $ax+by+c=0$ and $a'x+b'y+c'=0$ is
$$(ax+by+c)+L(a'x+b'y+c')=0$$
Where $L$ is any arbitrary constant.

How do I complete the rest?

Comment: Firstly, $K,L$ are _unknown_ constants, not "arbitrary" constants. Putting that minor nitpick aside, since the diagonals are perpendicular, the normal vectors for those two lines need to be perpendicular. That should clinch it.

Comment: @quasi, where does vector emerge for co-ordinates solution?

Comment: A line with equation of the form $Ax + By + C = 0$ has normal vector ${\langle}A,B{\rangle}$.

Comment: @quasi, I have never dealt cordinates using vectors. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's should be in your textbook. But this may not be the right approach since it only gives you _one_ equation.

Comment: @quasi, Under which topic should I search for it in my textbook?

Comment: Which textbook are you using (author, title, edition)?

Comment: This tedious problem must belong to SL loney.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two parallel lines in the $xy$-plane given by the equations

\begin{align*}
Ax+By+C_1 = 0\\[4pt]
Ax+By+C_2 = 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

the distance between them is given by the formula

$$\frac{\left|C_2 - C_1\right|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_between_two_straight_lines)

But given a parallelogram,

$$\text{the diagonals are perpendicular}$$
$$\text{if and only if}$$ 
$$\text{the parallelogram is a rhombus}$$
$$\text{if and only if}$$ 
$$\text{the distance between the pairs of opposite sides are equal}$$

Applying the above to the lines specified for the edges of your parallelogram, you get

$$
\frac{\left|c - c'\right|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} 
= 
\frac{\left|c - c'\right|}{\sqrt{(a')^2+(b')^2}}$$

which yields the condition

$$a^2+b^2 = (a')^2+(b')^2$$

Comment: Why are the distance between the pairs of opp. sides equal?

Comment: In a rhombus, all sides are equal. The area is equal to the product of any side and the altitude to that side, hence, since the sides are equal, so are the altitudes.

Answer (score 1):

$ax+by+c=0$ ...(1)

$a'x+b'y+c=0$ ...(2)

$ax+by+c'= 0$ ...(3)

$a'x+b'y+c'=0 $...(4)

Let P be the intersection of (1) and (2)

Equation of a line passing through P is given by

$ ax+by+c +K(a'x+b'y+c) = 0$ ...(5)

Let R be the intersection of (3) and (4) for which $ ax+by=-c'$ and $a'x+b'y=-c'$

Substituting in (5) $(c-c')+K(c-c') = 0$  or, $K = -1 $

Hence, from (5), $(a-a')x+(b-b')y=0$ ...(6). 
This is the equation of the diagonal PR.

Let S be the intersection of (1) and (4)

Equation of a line passing through S is given by

$ax+by+c + L(a'x+b'y+c') = 0 $ …….(7)

Let Q be the intersection of (2) and (3) for which $ax+by = -c'$ and $a'x+b'y = -c$

Substituting these in (5) $c-c'+L(c'-c) = 0$ or, $L=1 $

Substituting in (7), $(a+a')x+(b+b')y+c+c'=0$ ...(8). This is the equation of the diagonal QS.

Now slope of PR  is $$\frac{-(a-a')}{(b-b')}$$

slope of QS   is $$\frac{-(a+a')}{(b+b')}$$

Since the diagonals are perpendicular,
Product of slopes=$$\frac{-(a-a')}{(b-b')}*\frac{-(a+a')}{(b+b')} = \frac{a^{2}-a'^{2}}{b^{2}-b'^{2}}=-1$$

Hence ${a^{2}+b^{2}}={a'^{2}+b'^{2}}$